# No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [..] and content type [application/json]

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I use Spring for Android to parse my Json.

But I recently have this error :

> No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [...request.Temp] and content type [application/json]

Even if I use [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) which is able to handle application/json

Here is my request code :

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    headers.setAcceptEncoding(ContentCodingType.GZIP);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map=getParameters();

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

    RestTemplate template=getRestTemplate();
    template.setErrorHandler(new MyDefaultReponseErrorHandler());

    /* I also tried it
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter=new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> mediaTypeList=new ArrayList<>();
    mediaTypeList.add(new MediaType("application", "json"));
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypeList);
    */

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterList=new ArrayList<>();
    converterList.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    //converterList.add(converter);
    converterList.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    template.setMessageConverters(converterList);

    return template.postForObject(endPoint, entity, clazz);
```

And the object that I try to parse :

```
{
"error": null,
"result": [
    { .. some fields .. }
]
}
```

With :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class Temp {
private int error;
private ArrayList<Search> arrayList;

public int getError() {
    return error;
}

@JsonProperty("error")
public void setError(int error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public ArrayList<Search> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}

@JsonProperty("result")
public void setArrayList(ArrayList<Search> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}
}
```

With other functions (without array) of WebService this work.

Another thing that I find strange, when I parse the result with :

```
@JsonProperty("result")
 public void setResult(String string) {
    
}
```

I have error of parsing. It's normal, string different of array, but at least he try to parse.

So, an idea ?

**PS : I try on another function with array to parse, it works**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the bug, it come from my object Search (for my array of Search) :

```
@JsonProperty("start_date")
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

@JsonProperty("start_date")
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
```

I have used two times "start_date", the error message was not really explicit...